# No crontab command is working

Tags: debian, cron, crontab

[image: crontab debian]

user hacker belongs to sudoers

A command like `python2 slowloris /home/hacker/scripts/slowloris/slowloris.py 192.168.1.5 -s 1000` only works manually. The clock is synchronized!

syslog:

[image: syslog]

I dont know what to do!

Comment: for the slowloris command - you have extra `slowloris` when you call it from command line vs. cron. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have error in the crontab syntax. It's always 5 space-separated fields for time, sixth for user and remainder of line for the command. Specifically the last two commands:

> 30 18 * * * timeout 300 root hping3 -i -u1 -S 80 192.168.1.5
>
> 40 18 * * * timeout 300 root ./home/hacker/scripts/LOICfinal/loic 192.168.1.5

should be

> 30 18 * * * **root /usr/bin/timeout** 300 **/usr/sbin/hping3** -i -u1 -S 80 192.168.1.5
>
> 40 18 * * * **root /usr/bin/timeout** 300 **/home/hacker/scripts/LOICfinal/loic** 192.168.1.5

You should also consider to not run any scripts as root, which are writeable by regular user - in this case the scripts located in `hacker` home folder.

Comment: :hping3 is still not working! It works only manually!

Comment: Check `man hping3`, i suspect you have error in parameters. It should be `-i u3` instead of `-i -u3` because `-u` is another option without arguments allowed. TCP syn flag `-S` also doesn't accept parameters.